# plaintext credentials are showing in window event logs when connected to vcenter using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials, powercli, vcenter

@powershell
@vcenter

I have connected to vcenter with encrypted  password  as below. But still my plaintext  password  is getting logged in event  logs.

How can I make my credentials hide in log.

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssword134" -AsPlainText  -Force
```

Note: Above password  "P@ssword134" is not given hardcode. It Will get password  using our own API call from UI

```
$credentials  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user,$SecurePassword)

Connect-VIServer "vcenter IP address" -Credential $credentials
```

Path of logs is event viewer \Applications and Services Logs Microsoft \Windows \Powershell \Operational

Logging is as below:

> ParameterBinding(ConvertTo-SecureString): name ="String"; value
> ="P@ssword134"

This cleatrxt password before encryption's should  not showcase in log

Can someone  help this issue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, though I didn't connect to VCenter. Which versions are you running? [Edit] the question don't add version strings as a comment as those are ephemeral anyway.

Comment: PSVersion 5.1.14393.187 CLR version:4.0.30319.187

Comment: Edit your quesiton with a reproducible example. This does not happen when just using credentials, so assume it's got something to do with your parameter binding/coding.

Comment: @vonPryz I have updated commands used and also description

Comment: @Scepticalist parameter  binding  is not from my code...It's logging in log. Here the issue is plaintext  password  is converted to secure string and then stored in ps credentials  and then those credentials  passed to vcenter ApI call. But In these process plaintext  credentials  are stored and logged in the event logs.

Comment: If I run those 3 commands I don't get any such messages in the event log.
What is the event log ID, what is the FULL text of the event and how are you running the script? (VScode, ps1 etc). Once again, the error implies that you are using a function parameter to set/validate the password.

Comment: @Scepticalist event id is 4103. Running the script in powershell  ISE. Iam not validating the password,  plaintext  password  is just capturing In event logs. Apart from this there is no error. Script executed successfully. But the issue is showing password  in log, even though it encrypted. Read Host "ente password " -AssecureString prompt  will fix the issue.whixh will take password  from POP UP and convert to secure string but this is not helpful  to me. As so many scripts cannot be pop up for every execution.

Comment: You don't seem to have posted an actual reproducible example - the code you posted here does not produce the event ID or the behaviour that you describe.
Please post the ENTIRE Event detail and a reproducible example

Comment: @Scepticalist may be your logging  is not enabled or may be its in blocked state. So you are not getting  event logs in event viewer

Comment: It's enabled. I;ve tested on two systems - there's not enough info here to assist further,